# What are Apache Heap Dump files (extension hdmp)?

Tags: apache-2.2

There seems to be little literature regarding these files.  On a couple windows servers we see discovered huge (like almost 2gb) **httpd.exe.hdmp** files in the **documents and settings** folder.  In one specific instance:

C:\Documents and Settings\mschenkel\Local Settings\Temp\2\WER8299.dir00

- Are these some sort of log file which gets created when there is a problem with the server?
- Is it ok to delete them?
- Is there a setting in **httpd.conf** so they don't get created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are not generated by Apache per se, but by Windows when Apache (or another process has an error. From http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;949180

> Windows Error Reporting in Windows Server 2008 generates the following
>   information:
>
> ```
> A report manifest file (Report.wer)
> Operating system version information (.version.txt)
> Application information (.appcompat.txt)
> A heap dump file (.hdmp)
> A mini-dump file (.mdmp)
> ```
>
> However, you cannot access user-mode
>   process dump information by using this
>   feature.
>
> To configure Windows Error Reporting,
>   you can modify certain registry
>   settings. For more information about
>   how to do this, visit the following
>   Microsoft Web site:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx